# Can I "Find All References" on a primary constructor?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2022, c#-12.0

Using Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.3) how can I "find all references" on a c# 12 primary constructor?

I can use ReSharper (2023.2) and use 'find usages' but only (and very specifically) if the caret is immediately prior to the opening bracket of the primary constructor. This then gives me the prompt of what to search for as in the picture below.

I'd like to know if there is *any* way of performing find all references and also if there is a more convenient (and less precise) way of performing find usages.

[image: Find Usages]

Comment: Upgrade to ReSharper 2023.3 as that handles C#12 features better, if still an issue then raise it with Jetbrains.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that performing "find usages" on a type (when the caret is on the type name) is not suitable for you? Could you please explain why? And what behavior would you like to see in this case?

Comment: @MaryPleskunina "find usages" on a type works as I'd expect. In order to find usages of the constructor the caret has to be at position 54 (between 'l' and '(' ) this position (and no other) prompts to search for either the type or the constructor as per the screen grab above. I'm looking for a more convenient way to search for usages of a primary constructor.